# Counting Carousel Item and pause issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to count carousel item and for specific item pause by interval then cycle.
but I can not get item id!

Thanks

```
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

  console.log($(".item.active").prevAll().length);

  if($(".item.active").prevAll().length == 5) {  //  5 =  slide indexi 

    $('.carousel').carousel('pause');

    setTimeout(function() {

      $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');

    },5000);

  }

});
```

Comment: Post your HTML please. Also, why do you need item id?

Comment: https://codepen.io/brusky/pen/NyqqqG
after 3 loops I will change content dynamicaly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`index`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection

So you can use:

```
if($(".item.active").index() == 5) {  //  5 =  slide index (starting from 0)
```

In your case, index values are from 0 to 5.

**Edit**

I attached a working example. Note that the total showing time of the slide with index `5` is the sum of the carousel interval and the `milliseconds` parameter of `setTimeout` (which I set to `10000`). So in my example, the slide with index `5` will be displayed for 15 seconds (default carousel interval is `5000`).

```js
$('.carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {

  console.log($(".item.active").index());

  if ($(".item.active").index() === 5) { //  5 =  slide index 

    $('.carousel').carousel('pause');

    setTimeout(function() {

      $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');

    }, 10000);

  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="num"></div>
```

**Edit 2**

New solution based on comments on this answer

```js
var cycleCount = 0;

// Pause on the 3rd cycle when slide with index 2 is shown
var cycleCountPause = 3;
var slideIndexPause = 2;
var pauseInterval = 10000;

var $carousel = $('.carousel');

var slidesCount = $carousel.find('.carousel-inner .item').length;

$carousel.on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {

  var activeIndex = $carousel.find(".item.active").index();

  if (cycleCount === cycleCountPause && activeIndex === slideIndexPause) {
    $carousel.carousel('pause');

    setTimeout(function() {
      $carousel.carousel('cycle');
    }, pauseInterval);
  }

  if (activeIndex === slidesCount - 1) {
    cycleCount++;
  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="num"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I tested in my sample doesnt work and interval work as default(3-4 sec) also I used index but not solved yet :( in your sample when pause doesnt show the slide bu normally when pause on 2.slider  slider 2 should appear. What I need just after all slides finished will increase the counter  and when counter is 3 will pause with interval value maybe  I wrote wrong at firstThanks

Comment: Sorry @Brave but I don't understand. Could you please explain it again?

Comment: sorry,
https://codepen.io/brusky/pen/RQPKRR
after show all slider(3 image in my sample) it should count index when index is 3 must pause with interval 10000 then cycle

Comment: this my mistake :( sorry all images that in slider only appear 3 times then pause (not only pause specific slider item ) slider must working 3 times from begining to end then pause with interval hope my comment is clear 
Thanks alot

Comment: just last question change index as 3 does not pause
https://codepen.io/brusky/pen/RQPKRR
the important thing is that after we see active item we should pause then after interval will work again then pause again then interval sorry I could not explain well :(

Comment: So do you want to show a complete cycle for 3 times (slide 0 to 2, 0 to 2, 0 to 2) and then pause?

Comment: Yes Omar exactly, and additionally should allow to choose item to pause for example 3.cycle and 2.item or 3.item pause
thanks

Comment: Ok @Brusky I updated my answer. Please update your question to better explain what you asked.

Comment: just additional question once pause after 3.cycle  2.slide and 10000 interval then start sliding but not count again just did once, not looping cycle loop again.
is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: OK Thanks,
For looping after the cycle I made cycleCount = 0; now looping every 3 cycle and 2.slide

Comment: Good job @Brusky :) Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

See This Working Demo :

initially we have set interval of 1 second , 
then on `slid.bs.carousel`

> slid.bs.carousel: This event is fired when the carousel has completed
>   its slide transition.

we pause slide number 2 of index 1 for 5 seconds and then cycle the carousel.

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 1000
})


$('#carouselExampleControls').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
  var total= $('div.carousel-item').length;
  var currentIndex = $('div.active').index();
  if(currentIndex==1){
  
    $('#carouselExampleControls').carousel('pause');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
    },5000);

  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://more-cliparts.net/images/6ir5EAgAT.png">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/y/G/s/h/j/O/two-md.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.competitivefutures.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/three.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    
     <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://www.analyticalones.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/four.png" alt="Fourth slide">
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```